# Firefox add-on sdk: Finding total number of nested iframes(cross domain) in a page?

Tags: javascript, iframe, firefox-addon-sdk

I wanna write an extension using Firefox add-on sdk, and I need to know the total number of all iframes(nested, and probably cross domain) of a page. In order to do that I used pageMod and the following contentScript(each iframe says hello to the top window, so we can keep track of their numbers):

```js
setTimeout(function(){
         window.top.postMessage('I am a new iframe, url : ' + window.location.href
        ,'*');
},1000);
```

And I listen to the messages from iframe by the following code:

```js
window.addEventListener('message',function(event) {
                number_of_frame++;
        },false);
```

Is there any simpler way to do this? Any API that gives me this functionality so I can avoid message passing between any iframe and the top window?

Answer (score 1):

If I did not make some typos, then this untested code will do what you want. It adds itself to the `body` of all the `iframe`s inside the current `window` and then the `iframe`s will become current `window`s themselves. `iFrameCount` starts from -1, since we will count the main `window` as well.

```
var iFrameCount = -1;

var scriptToInject = '<script type="text/javascript">window.top.iFrameCount++;$("iframe").each(function() {$(this).contents().find("body").append(window.top.scriptToInject);});</script>';
$("body").append(scriptToInject);
```

Comment: That's great answer for cases where all iframe s are from the same origin, but in case of cross domain iframe, I don't have access to a global variable in the main window.

Comment: Good point. You can do it, by having an API function where you send requests.